# Copy and Paste (transposed & values) a set range in a different sheet in the next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I have some data in `range P1:R13` on a sheet called Training Analysis.
I want to `copy and paste` these data on a second sheet called Foglio1. I want it to be just `values`. I need these data to be pasted in a `range A2:M4`, in other words I want it to be transposed. 
I got the following code and it is working. But now, when I get new data I need to paste them under those I already have.

```
Sub add()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Foglio1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row    ' or + 1
    Range("P1:R13").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Foglio1").Range("A" & lastrow)
End Sub
```

It does the empty space but I don't know how to change it to make it transpose the data and give me only values. 
Can you help me change it ? If you have new options its fine too.
Cheers

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do when you have a question like this is to record a macro, understand how it works and then clean up the code.

This is what you will get after doing what you need manually and recording it:

```
Range("P1:R13").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Foglio1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
```

After you clean it up a bit and add determining the last row this is what you should get:

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Sheets("Training Analysis").Range("P1:R13").Copy

lastRow = Sheets("Foglio1").Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Foglio1").Range("A" & lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

In this particular case you didn't know that you need to  use the PasteSpecial method but this is okay: you don't need to remember the entire Excel object model by heart. You can use the 'record, clean up and modify' method whenever you are in a situation like this.

Comment: This code is working properly, thank you ! I've also tried to record a macro but then i was not able to clean up and modify as you did.

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten it further and try:

```
Sub add()
    Range("Foglio1!A2:M4").Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.transpose(Range("Training Analysis!P1:R13").Value2)
End Sub
```

This is, of course, adapted to this specific case, so, for further use, you must ensure you update the sheet names and ranges(if they change). You also have to check by yourself that the areas are equivalent (e.g. 15x2 to 5x6 cells). These checks can be added in the procedure, but the code above should do the trick for the moment.

EDIT: I saw your specification a bit too late. :)
Here is the adapted code, which should find the first available row on sheet "Foglio1", column A, and will paste the transposed values onto a 3x13 area. Give it a go.

```
Sub add2()
    With Sheets("Foglio1")
        .Cells(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).Resize(3, 13).Value2 = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Training Analysis").Range("P1:R13").Value2)
    End With
End Sub
```

EDIT 2: updated `add2` so that the source range would refer to sheet "Training Analysis" and prevent error# 1004.

Comment: Thank you for answering me i really appreciate that. I don't know if i'm wrong but i got a bug when i run this macro. Is seems something is wrong with the third line (.Cells.....).

Comment: What message do you get for that line?

Comment: Just the entire cell highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Odd, I don't get any error.
A message should display on errors. What settings do you have for Error Trapping?
I use "Break on All Errors". The setting is done via Menu: Tools » Options » Tab: General, Group: Error Trapping.

With that setting, you can step into each line (pressing F8 from the first line to the last) and the error window should pop up.

Comment: ok i did it, when i run the code i got "range" of the object "_Global" failed

Comment: You can follow the steps above for error trapping, then copy the whole 'add2' sub, place the cursor inside the sub and just press F5. Should there be an error, it should pop up. The message you mentioned shows up because you didn't end the subroutine with `End Sub`.

Comment: Ok i did the F5 check and it gives me the same error. I ended the subroutine with End Sub.

Comment: I renamed my sheets to catch the error and, indeed, it throws error #1004, due to the source Range referring to an uninstantiated object.
The second part of the assignment should read:
`Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets("Training Analysis").Range("P1:R13").Value2)`
This should work now. I have also edited my answer accordingly.